# Application of data objects in BPMN

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, processmaker

Recently I've started a ‌BPMS project. I have read a lot about BPMN2 but I do not know exactly data objects and data store application.

In some cases data object is used to display files. For example in this diagram, Upload Expense Support File looks for a file but Data Input construct for modeling input data within the Process flow!!??

[image]

In other case data object is used to instance of Folio class (Folio table in database)

[image]

I'm confused. What is application of data object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Data Stores* are permanent. The information a process writes to a Data Stores is available after the process instance terminates.

*Data Objects* exists for the scope of the process. Only if a *Data Object* is defined as a *Data Output Object* it exists beyond the scope of the process.

So you should use *Data Objects* for explicit process inputs/outputs and documents that are created **ad-hoc** and **later discarded**.

*Data Stores*, should be used if your process creates, alters or consumes to generally persisting information.